# How to converte geometry of an object from GLTF to JSON?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, three.js, mesh, react-three-fiber

I have generated a GLTF file with a cube object using Blender. I would need to find out if there is a way to get the geometry of this cube from this GLTF file and save it as JSON in a database. I then need to call the geometry of this object from the API and render it in the application like this:

```
const { data: geometryData } = useGetGeometry();

<mesh
   castShadow
   geometry={geometryData}
   material={Where will be my castomized material}
   rotation={...} // I don't need to store the rotation in that JSON
   scale={...} // scale doesn't need to be stored in this JSON
/>
```

Is it possible to do this?